# Finding and counting the frequency of known pairs of words in multiple files

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sequence

Basically I need to count the number of word pairs in multiple files. I have a list of word pairs in a file called `result.txt`, which looks like:

1. the of
2. the by
3. they is
4. group their

I want to check the frequency of these pairs in many text files located in a given directory, and print the pair sequence and the corresponding frequency in decreasing order. The output must be of the form:

1. group their 205
2. they is     180
3. the of      56

I already tried the following:

```
import os
import re
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools as it

folderpath = 'path/to/directory'
pairs=defaultdict(int)

logfile = open('result.txt', 'r')
loglist = logfile.readlines()
logfile.close()
found = False
for line in loglist:
    for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt')):
        with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
            for pair in it.combinations(re.findall('\w+',line),2):
                pairs[tuple(pair)]+=1
    found=True                    
resultList=[pair+(occurences, ) for pair, occurences in pairs.iterkeys()]
```

But it is not giving me the expected result. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Aaaaan the question iiiiis?

Comment: why is self undefined here?

Comment: What do you expect `self` to be?

Comment: This question is obviously braindead copypasta homework.

Comment: Is `self` undefined? What is the traceback (the full one), i.e. what error are you getting? You don't appear to have a single reference to `self`.

Comment: @Ben, there was a self, but it was removed at the same time the question was added, which makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that @Mark. user2464521, you have now edited the question 5 times but you still haven't explained _why_ your code isn't doing what you expect or whether there is an error, or what that error is.

Comment: i don't get any output, obviously there is a defect, plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `combinations()` you are getting all pairs, even the non-adjacent ones. You can create a function that will return the adjacent pairs. I've tried the following code and it worked, maybe it can give you some insight:

```
import os
import re
from collections import Counter

def pairs(text):
    ans = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', text)
    return (tuple(ans[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(len(ans)-1))

mypairs = tuple([ tuple(line.split()[-2:]) for line in open('results.txt')])

c = Counter()
folderpath = 'path/to/directory'
for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(folderpath):
    for f in fnames:
        if not '.txt' in f: continue
        for line in open(os.path.join(dirpath, f)):
            c += Counter(p for p in pairs(line) if p in mypairs)

for item in c.most_common():
    print item
```

Comment: i don't get the output!for line in fileinput.input(iglob(os.path.join(folderpath, '*.txt')))
    c += Counter(p for p in pairs(line) if p in mypairs), doesn't work out,could you suggest another alternative?

Comment: @user2464521 I changed to `os.walk` which is pretty much easier to understand and easy to recursively find all the '.txt' files